# server ask for root password after reboot while logging in with ssh key

Tags: ssh

after rebooting Linux server (centos 7) I'm trying to login with ssh key seems it's successfully loging in but asks to change root password which I've forgotten. Is there a way to bypass changing root password and login with ssh key?

```
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: ...
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Comment: Are you able to run other commands? `ssh w.x.y.z /bin/ls` for example, if that works then you might be able to execute your shell without running login scripts. That's assuming this is enforced by a login script

Comment: @RobbieMckennie no I get this error: WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.